# Can the Detect Magic spell sense an object that is followed by Locate Object?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

A character used [*Detect Magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) on a non-magical object that was being followed by a [*Locate Object*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/locate-object) spell.

Does the wizard player sense an aura on it, or not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### The object has no magic aura.

The target of *Locate Object* is the caster, not the searched object: the range of the spell is Self, the spell is affecting the caster, not the object.

The text of *Detect Magic* says (emphases mine):

> For the duration, **you sense the presence of magic within 30 feet of you**. If you sense magic in this way, you can use your action to see a faint aura around **any visible creature** or object in the area that bears magic, and you learn its school of magic, if any.

When *Detect Magic* is active, one may see a faint aura around the caster of Locate Object, since the caster is bearing the magical effects provided by the spell.

Comment: While this is still probably RAW, the spell being range "self" by no means guarantees it is not detectable; *Scrying* has a range of "self", and it creates a sensor [which is definitely detectable](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90084/does-detect-magic-allow-detection-of-scrying). A DM might reasonably rule that all long-distance divination effects work similarly.

Comment: @Dragonfang That spell creates a magical effect that is external to the caster: it is a different case. The spell description states that the sensor is clearly detectable under specific circumstances.